# python subprocess calling bash script - need to print the quotes out too

Tags: python, bash, subprocess

I'm having a problem with subprocess and printing quotes.

My Python script takes user input, mashes it around a bit - and I need it to send it's results to a bash script in this manner.

```
myscript.sh 'var1 == a var2 == b; othervar == c' /path/to/other/files
```

Where I'm getting hung up on is the single quotes.  Python tries to rip them out.

I used this for my test.

```
subprocess.Popen([myscript.sh 'var=11; ignore all' /path/to/files], shell=True, executable="/bin/bash")
```

which returns an invalid syntax pointing at the 2nd single quote.  I've also tried the above without the brackets and using single quotes outside and double quotes inside, etc.

Other - would-like.

As I was saying above the  'var == a var == b; othervar == c'  is derived from the python script (in string format) - and I'll need to call that in the subprocess like this.

```
subprocess.Popen([myscript.sh myvariables /path/to/files], shell=True, executable="/bin/bash")
```

I just have to put the single quotes around the value of myvariables like the first example.

Any pointers as to where I'm going off the correct method?

Thank you.

Comment: I think we aready has this error today. What makes people think this is remotely valid syntax? List items are seperated by commas, period. And a blank `foo` has nothing to do with the string `"foo"`. (Also: I couldn't fine the example you quote, would you mind giving out a line number?)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When shell=True is passed to Popen, you pass whatever you would send on the command line. That means your list should only have one element. So for example:

```
subprocess.Popen(['myscript.sh "var=11; ignore all" /path/to/files'], shell=True, executable="/bin/bash")
```

Or if /path/to/files is a variable in your Python environment:

```
subprocess.Popen(['myscript.sh "var=11; ignore all" %s' % path_to_files], shell=True, executable="/bin/bash")
```

Having said that I **STRONGLY** encourage you not to use the shell argument. The reason is fragility. You'll get a much more robust way of doing it like this:

```
subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "myscript.sh", "var=11; ignore all", path_to_files])
```

Note that "var=11; ignore all" is passed as one argument to your script. If those are separate arguments, make them separate list elements.

Comment: Another reason not to use `shell=True` is that it can be insecure, depending on where the input is coming from. It's possible to feed it input that will execute other commands on your system.

Comment: couldn't get it to work without shell=True, but this did work.  subprocess.Popen(['myscript.sh "%s" %s ' % (varfilter, thepath)], shell=True, executable="/bin/bash"

Answer (score 2):

I haven't checked why this works, but it does and without the need for shell=True.

```
subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "myscript.sh", '""' + string_to_be_quoted + '""', path_to_files])
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a list, those are strings in it, so they need quotes:

```
["myscript.sh", "var=11; ignore all", "/path/to/files"]
```

That should work. If your script really somehow relies on quotes, then try this (I don't know the details of how subprocess works):

```
["myscript.sh", "'var=11; ignore all'", "/path/to/files"]
```

Comment: I believe `subprocess` takes care of adding quote when necessary - if it goes trough the shell at all (I figure there are ways of invoking a program and specifying the arguments that don't require to glue executable name and arguments in one large string to be parsed by some shell ;))

Comment: That's not actually true in this case. If you're using shell=True, then subprocess lets the shell figure out the quotes. It's literally what you would type on the command line.

Comment: @Ken: You're right, I'd missed the use of the `shell=True` argument.