# Python's popen, bash scripts and CentOS

Tags: python, apache, bash, popen

I'm running a Django server from Apache that starts a Bash script (/usr/bin/tf) via subprocess.popen. My problem is that I can't access a particular directory from the Bash script **but** it really doesn't seem like a permissions problem. The executing user, confirmed by running **whoami** from within the Bash script is *apache*.

Note: /usr/bin/tf is the Bash script being executed via Bash. /usr/lib/tfs is the directory containing dependencies for the Bash script.

Python popen call:

```
subprocess.Popen(['/bin/bash', '/usr/bin/tf'],
                 env=env,
                 stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                 stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                 close_fds=(os.name != 'nt'))
```

I have also tried using **shell=True** (just to see if that would resolve the issue). In all cases save for **shell=True**, I can't even get a valid list from **ls /**. With **shell=True** I can see **ls /** all the way up to **ls /usr/bin**; however, I still cannot access the libs folder for tf at /usr/lib/tfs/lib. I can see the content in /usr/lib. By "cannot access", I really mean "ls" calls return a blank line instead of a file/directory list.

I'm executing the Bash script through /bin/bash per [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798331/python-subprocess-calling-bash-script-need-to-print-the-quotes-out-too)'s recommendation.

I've tried a few things to make sure the permissions should at least work:

```
chown -R apache:apache /usr/lib/tfs
chmod -R 7777 /usr/lib/tfs (obviously bad but should have worked...)

chown -R --reference=/usr/lib /usr/lib/tfs
chmod -R --reference=/usr/lib /usr/lib/tfs
```

In short, is there something restricting file access from a process when started in Python with popen?

**Update 2**
Executing "ls -la /usr/lib" has shown something very strange, all ?'s for the directory permissions of /usr/lib/tfs.

```
d??????????  ? ?    ?         ?            ? tfs
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root   4096 Jul  1 17:08 udev
drwxr-xr-x. 15 root root   4096 Jul 31 14:09 vmware-tools
drwxr-xr-x.  4 root root   4096 Jul  7 04:26 x86_64-redhat-linux5E
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root   4096 Jul  1 17:10 yum-plugins
```

Comment: What do you mean by "can't access" exactly? Presumably `/usr/bin/tf` doesn't work when you run it but in what way? Is there a reason you are running `tf` through `bash` for this instead of just running it directly? What user is this running as? Can that user run `tf` manually? Using `['/bin/bash', '/usr/bin/tf']` is only going to work if `tf` is a shell script and not if it is a binary since that tries to run `/bin/bash /usr/bin/tf` which, well try it yourself and see.

Comment: tf is a Bash script, I should have been more clear. Investigating pointed to popen emulating a shell but lacking common shell functionality, so most people will execute a bash script via bash.

tf does execute properly but within the script I can't access directories. The executing user is apache (as it's instigated from Django running through apache).

Executing tf directly, not through bash, works similarly but lacks access to some common commands (namely, cd). I don't need that and I initially was trying without Bash but still had the same result.

Comment: You still didn't explain "can't access directories". What does that mean exactly? What *exactly* is failing and are there any errors?

Comment: Within the bash, if I execute "ls /usr/lib/tfs", I get a blank line. No error, just a blank line. I do get a list of files/directories with "ls /" or even "ls /usr/lib", just not tfs. Note, this is only the case when i use shell=True. If I don't use shell=True then I always get blank lines from "ls anything" except for the current directory (ie. "ls" but not "ls .", that always gives a blank line).

Comment: How are you executing those commands from "[w]ithin the bash"? `['/bin/bash', 'ls /usr/lib/tfs']`? Because that isn't doing what you think it is. Check stderr on that subprocess call and see what you get.

Comment: ... /usr/bin/tf is a bash script. In the bash script I have ls /usr/lib/tfs... /bin/bash executes /usr/bin/tf, not /usr/lib/tfs or "ls /usr/lib/tfs"

Comment: I'd love to know why my question was down voted.

Comment: That sounds like a corrupted filesystem somehow. Can you deal with that directory normally outside of this script? (I feel like this was answered somewhere but I couldn't find it in a quick skim just now.)

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/65616/question-marks-showing-in-ls-of-directory-io-errors-too but it hasn't resolved the question marks. Further, ls -la as root or even as apache (su apache -s /bin/bash) does not show the ?s.

Comment: Did you have read but not execute permissions on the directory for the apache user? Are you sure `tf` is running as that user in this context (print that information out from within the `tf` script?)?

Comment: Yes, I ran whoami from tf and it was apache. It appears to be a permissions issue going from a zip I can only assume to be from Windows to Linux. The tf stands for Team Foundation, the cross-platform Team Foundation Server tool. I'm guessing the permissions in the directories are somehow screwed up. I'm in the process of recreating directories and moving files over which has appeared to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The directory permissions, though seemingly fine when logged in as root or apache (using *su apache -s /bin/bash*) were screwed up for the executing bash script. My suspicion is that the directories originated from a Windows machine and that had a hand in the invalid permission settings.

The fix was actually to just copy the target directory and use the copy, deleting the old one.

```
mv /usr/lib/tf /usr/lib/tfold
cp /usr/lib/tfold /usr/lib/tf
rm -rf /usr/lib/tfold
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try:

```
#!/usr/local/cpython-3.4/bin/python

# pylint: disable=superfluous-parens
# superfluous-parens: Parentheses are good for clarity and portability

'''Start tf'''

# Runs on 2.[4567] and 3.[01234]

import os
import subprocess


def main():
    '''Main function'''
    stuff = subprocess.Popen(
        ['/bin/bash', '/usr/local/bin/tf'],
        env=os.environ,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        close_fds=(os.name != 'nt'),
    )
    stdout, dummy = stuff.communicate()
    os.write(1, stdout)

main()
```

HTH

BTW, don't try to run "ls -l".  Instead do ['ls', '-l'] unless you give shell=True.