# Run bash scripts in parallel from python script

Tags: python, bash, parallel-processing

I'm facing a problem in python:

My script, at a certain point, has to run some test script written in bash, and I have to do it in parallel, and wait until they end.
I've already tried :

```
os.system("./script.sh &")
```

inside a for loop but it did not worked.

Any suggest?

Thank you!

**edit**

I have nt correctly explained my situation:
My phyton script resides in the home dir;
my sh scripts resides in other dirs, for instance /tests/folder1 and /tests/folder2;

Trying to use os.system implies the usage of os.chdir prior to call os.system (to avoid troubles on "no such files or directory", my .sh scripts contains some relative references), and also this method is blocking my terminal output.

Trying to use Popen and passing all the path fro home folder to my .sh lead to launch zombie processes without any responses or other.

Hope to find a solution,

Thank you guys!

Comment: Have you checked out the `thread` module? https://docs.python.org/2/library/thread.html or `multiprocessing`? https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: What do you want to happen to the script stdout and stderr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you use GNU Parallel?

```
ls test_scripts*.sh | parallel
```

Or:

```
parallel ::: script1.sh script2.sh ... script100.sh
```

GNU Parallel is a general parallelizer and makes is easy to run jobs in parallel on the same machine or on multiple machines you have ssh access to. It can often replace a `for` loop.

If you have 32 different jobs you want to run on 4 CPUs, a straight forward way to parallelize is to run 8 jobs on each CPU:

[image: Simple scheduling]

GNU Parallel instead spawns a new process when one finishes - keeping the CPUs active and thus saving time:

[image: GNU Parallel scheduling]

**Installation**

If GNU Parallel is not packaged for your distribution, you can do a personal installation, which does not require root access. It can be done in 10 seconds by doing this:

```
(wget -O - pi.dk/3 || curl pi.dk/3/ || fetch -o - http://pi.dk/3) | bash
```

For other installation options see http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/tree/README

**Learn more**

See more examples: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html

Watch the intro videos: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Walk through the tutorial: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html

Sign up for the email list to get support: https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/parallel

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor)?  The convenience functions `call` and `check_output` block, but the default `Popen` object doesn't:

```
processes = []
processes.append(subprocess.Popen(['script.sh']))
processes.append(subprocess.Popen(['script2.sh']))
...

return_codes = [p.wait() for p in processes]
```

Comment: I've tried your solution but it raises:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hotspot-generator.py", line 104, in <module>
    processes.append(subprocess.Popen(['run_all_synthetic2.sh']))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/4798456/4571544 on how to run shell scripts with ```subprocess.Popen```

Comment: @panc_fab -- You might need to specify a path to the executable... e.g. `Popen(['./run_all_synthetic2.sh'])`

Comment: thank you guys for the support, but it seems that all of your responses don't fit my problem. I've tried with Popen as suggested, but this leads in zombified processes. 

Probably it is due to the fact that I'm running the script on a university server so it might be that I can not spawn background processes, or there are some strict policies on that server.